In a sentence like "The discipline studies the political and economic patterns of the world," what is really going on?

The discipline studies the political and economic patterns of the world.

The intended meaning of the sentence is clear; but upon closer scrutiny, one notices that it is, of course, not the discipline itself that "studies", but rather the people working in it who "study" (and in particular, one can somewhat confusingly say that they study the discipline). What exactly is going on? Is it a grammatical matter, or a stylistic one? (The word metonymy comes to mind -- is it really that, or is it something else?) How formal is it?

Googling for example "anthropology studies" shows lots of hits on university websites e.g. wwu.edu "The discipline of anthropology studies humans in all the cultures of the world, both past and present." Aberdeen Uni in the UK: "Anthropology studies humans in an international context." This is a common usage. I can't see any prohibition or usage notes (did you research to try and find any or is this just your own intuition) but maybe there are usage guides that don't like it, as there are usage guides that don't like everything else.

What is "the discipline itself" if not a collection of people with a shared interest. All that is happening is that the verb is being distributed to the collection's members.

Yes, I think this is a kind of metonymy. Just like referring to the White House or Kremlin when you mean Biden or Putin (or the people that work for them).

Thanks, @EdwinAshworth, it does!

@StuartF I'd found the example on wikipedia, and wasn't sure to what extent it was good practice to use it in formal texts (I hadn't seen the univeristy websites, thanks.)

@PhilSweet Hmm... but people can "study the discipline", so that doesn't sound legit!
